# How to convert SQL Server CE 3.5 database to 4.0 in VS2012

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-ce

I've just upgraded my Visual Studio from 2010 to 2012 on Windows 7 64 bit. I have a windows forms project that uses a SQL Server CE database, currently v3.5. I've tried to upgrade the DB to 4.0 but I keep hitting a wall and haven't been able to find an article that helps. I looked at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172032.aspx but the instructions don't work. I get a error for a null object reference.

I did change the SQL Server CE 3.5 reference in my project to 4.0. I've even tried adding a new SQL Server CE database but VS only seems to have the option to add a 3.5 DB. I do have 4.0 installed on my system. I tried downloading SQL Server CE Toolbox but the option to convert the database is not offered. I get another error when I try to create a SQL Server CE 4.0 connection. It's like you can't get there from here! I thought about creating a new SQL Server CE 4.0 database and then adding it to my project but I'm getting nowhere doing that either. I used the 3.5 version of SQL Server CE toolbox to export the table scripts from my database so I do have that. I just can't seem to get to first base with VS2012 on this.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: What do I need to do to convert this database?  Failing that, how do I reconfigure VS2012 to add a new empty sqlce 4.0 database.  I created a test project this morning (MVC4/Razor) and successfully added a new empty sqlce 4.0 database.  All attempts to convert the DB in the converted VS2010 project have failed.

Comment: Download my toolbox, add a new v 4 connection, and upgrade when prompted

Comment: Tried that as part of my initial effort.  I can't add the v4 connection.  DB name is required or the OK button doesn't light up.  Once DB name is specified and OK is clicked I get a null object reference error.  What I finally did was to use your (excellent!) tool to recreate the DB tables in my test project.  I copied that db file into this project and re-referenced.  Now I have all kinds of warnings to resolve after I deleted the old dataset that was associated with the old DB.  The project now compiles, runs and I'm able to query and see expected data.  What a pain!

Comment: BTW, closed, reopened VS2012.  Reference errors now all gone.  That's good.  Tried adding a new local DB, only SQLCE 3.5 is available on offer.  Luckily I probably will never have to add a 2nd DB to this particular project, but still, this really, er, bugs me!  If you'll pardon the pun.